# Zuul - Single point of Failure

Tags: microservices, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

`Zuul` being used to work with `Eureka`/`Edge Services` stands out to be a single point of failure? Is there any way around it to make this scalable and resilient?

Comment: Hi @Divs, Did you find any solution?

Comment: @027 https://github.com/Netflix/zuul/issues/345.

Answer (score 3):

You can run multiple instance of zuul behind a load balancer.